# VBA: Set excel date format for all system date formats

Tags: excel, vba

Which date format is good to use in excel that should support all types of system date format???

Problem : If system date format is 'dd.mmm.yyyy',it`s not working when I put my date value format as 'dd-mmm-yyyy' -> it`s displaying it as '14.02.2013' instead of '14.Feb.2013'.

Please suggest me a date format that supports all system type date formats(English,German,Spanish,Mexican).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ISO8601 format - yyyy-mm-dd - example 2013-02-14